# Yii Can't Run Well After hosted

Tags: php, yii

Anyone can help me?
I create a website with Yii, when I run in localhost everything runs well, but after I upload using different server the `Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;` and some command of yii can't be read.
For example: with localhost I type `Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;`, it can result my project name. It show `/coretankuyii../images/fahrudin.jpg`. When I use different server the name of project can't be read, it results `../images/fahrudin.jpg`.
So whats the cause?

Comment: that looks correct to me.
the `Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;` will have the main path to start off so in localhost its showing the folder your project is in so the system knows where to look. on the live server there is no folder I.E localhost/project/images it will simply be domain-name.com/images

hope this helps

Comment: thanks for your idea, I wanna do it later.